Why did Pavitr questions Gwen and Miles concentration?
In a bustling market, Pavitr collides with Gwen while chasing Spot. Miles, also in pursuit,
converses with Spot about his inner void. Despite a billboard collision, Miles reassures his
well-being and the chase continues. Amidst this, Pavitr comments on the palpable romantic
tension, leaving the outcome uncertain:

Miles: If Spot gets more holes...he'll be unstoppable. We can't let
him get to...
GWEN: Alchemax?
Pavitr: See? How can you guys even concentrate?

Why did Pavitr questions Gwen and Miles concentration?

It's a reference to his previous sentence in the script. He does a sort of fourth-wall-breaking chat to the audience about Miles and Gwen of having palpable sexual tension. Then, when Gwen finishes Miles' sentence, he asks how they can even function without acknowledging it.
They ignore him, but he continues with the quipping.

PAVITR: This romantic tension is so palpable. Will they? Won’t they?
MILES: If Spot gets more holes, he’ll be unstoppable. We can’t let him get to [...]
GWEN: Alchemax?
PAVITR: See? How can you guys even concentrate?!

